# Generic Object typecasting

Tags: java, casting

I have an object, want to convert the generic object to class object. I thought the following should work. But it doesn't:

```
Object o1=itr.next();
Class cls=o1.getClass();
Object obj=(cls) o1;
```

What can the error be? How can I do this correctly?

Update: Here i have the list of objects that belongs to different classes. I will be using each class  in each loop to convert to XML or JSON string. for this i want to get the class and object it belongs.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the [cast method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) on the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object:

```
cls.cast(o1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This syntax:

```
Object obj=(cls) o1;
```

is not allowed. You can only cast to a *type* and `cls` is an *object* of type `Class`, not a type itself. What are you trying to accomplish with this? You could just as well write:

```
Object obj = o1;
```

since any reference type is assignment-compatible with `Object` (and, besides, `o1` is already of type `Object`).

Comment: so anyway to typecast??..i cant directly specify the class as it can be the set of classes...

Comment: @CodeJack: please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CodeJack You're trying to cast `o1` to its actual type? You can't really do that, at least using the code fragment you've shown us. Usually, `itr` is a generic class (that is, it has some sort of type parameter) and the type parameter defines the specific type of object it returns.

Comment: yea...so the class created will be what?...just Class or the original class it beongs to???

Comment: @CodeJack When you call `o1.getClass()`, you get back an instance of the actual class of `o1`. However, your code still won't know what that class is. I really can't tell what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide some context? I see that you accepted a solution and commented that "its working". What does it mean to be "working"?

Comment: @Ted hmm datz the issue.i guess 'cls.cast(obj)' should do the job for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Object o1=itr.next();
Class cls=o1.getClass();
Object obj=(cls) o1; //whats does it make sense casting Object by object? o1 and obj both are object
```

and it can be cast by type `T`, not class

Comment: That's true, referencing a casted object in a variable of type `Object` doesn't make sense. But it's useful for calling methods on it (and that's probably what the OP wanted to do): `cls.cast(o1).clsHasAMagicMethod()`.

Comment: @Koraktor That would make sense if `cls` were some known class, but the only thing OP's code would get you is another `Object` since `cls` doesn't have any declared generic type parameter.

Comment: @Koraktor id we know name of `clsHasAMagicMethod()` then we must know class so we can do more simple `((classname) o1).clsHasAMagicMethod()`

Comment: @All.Thanks for clarity. I just need the typecasted object for passing into some other function which returns me the XML structure of the object.

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond: Yes, I must admit my sample was a bit too simplified too. But you could also try to reflect methods or, like CodeJack does, pass the objects to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If your iterator returns Objects that actually are of the type Class this might work:

```
Object o1=itr.next();
Class clazz = (Class)o1;
```

To be honest, your question is not really clear to me.